# Returning 2 values from a subquery function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    utover.startnr, utover.navn
FROM 
    utover, deltakelse
WHERE 
    utover.startnr = (SELECT utover
                      FROM deltakelse
                      GROUP BY utover
                      HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                         FROM deltakelse
                                         GROUP BY utover
                                         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
                                         LIMIT 1)
                      LIMIT 1);
```

Here is the code I am using to get one of the two answers. I just wonder if it is possible to get more than one answer out somehow?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.  Your query doesn't do your problem justice in explaining what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the table `deltakelse` in the `from` clause.  Without this, you can probably get rid of the `distinct`.

The answer to your question is to change the `=` to an `in`:

```
SELECT utover.startnr, utover.navn
FROM utover
WHERE utover.startnr in (SELECT utover
                         FROM deltakelse
                         GROUP BY utover
                         HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                            FROM deltakelse
                                            GROUP BY utover
                                            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                                            LIMIT 1
                                           )
                        );
```